# Add an entity as LOG during property changing events of another entity

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows

I am using linq to sql in a windows form application. there is a bug that I couldn't find the solution until now!

```
partial void OnAmountChanging(int? value)
{
    OrderLog lg = new OrderLog()
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now,
        IPAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(Environment.MachineName)[0].ToString(),
        NewData = value,
        OldData = this.Amount,
        Status = "Changed",
        User = User.CurUser,
        Order = this // each Order has one-to-many relation to OrderLog entity. 
    };
}
```

this is run as soon as the value of AMOUNT changes in datagridview.
after closing the form I try to save the created log to Database:

```
db.SubmitChanges();
```

then I face this error :

> An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext. This is not supported

is there any solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549496/an-attempt-has-been-made-to-attach-or-add-an-entity-that-is-not-new-perhaps-hav

Comment: How do you attach your object to the database context? `db.OrderLogs.Add(lg)`? Can we see that code. And is this Entity Framework?

Comment: @gunr2171 The OP states it is LINQ2SQL

Comment: @gunr2172 this line: Order = this;

Comment: I just want to log the changes of properties of Order entity in my database, using the propertychanging event.